# CSS over-positioning elements

Tags: css, html, positioning

I have this code:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="image_thumbnail">
        <div class="category"></div>
        <div class="category2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info_thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="footer_thumbnail">
        <div class="stars_empty"></div>
    <img class="views" src="images/views.png">10
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I have to work on css to have an effect like this?
The green `div` should be the category `div`

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
​<div id="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="tab"></div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​



​#container{
position:relative;
}

​.​box{
position:relative;
left:10px;
top:10px;
height:150px;
width:100px;
border-radius:8px;
border:2px solid #666;
background-color:#DDD;
z-index:5;
}

.tab {
position:absolute;
left:105px;
top:35px;
width:25px;
height:40px;
background-color:green;
border-radius:5px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888;
}
```

​Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7RkR/

Answer (score 0):

What you'd like to do is not much clear.
Anyway, to handle over-positions you should have a main container for each of your thumbnail; set position:relative to the main container, and set position:absolute to each child layer element.

Comment: The green div should be hidden behind the thumbnail such that the only part that is not covered by the thumbnail its seen

Comment: Try what I suggested: the external container has relative positioning, each child has absolute positioning (you can then play with top/left or margins). Manage the z-order by ordering your html declarations (last element will be over the first) or by z-index